# Mysql Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\ip_allow_deny.lib.php on line 20

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was modifying my table via phpmyadmin(version 3.5.1) when I got this error as soon as I clicked on a table named "networking", all the others table are working fine but whenever I click on networking the error is the same, I went through these question

[Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176773/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-c)

[Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ...\model.php on line 183](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627031/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-model-php-on-l)

This is the exact error I am getting

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\ip_allow_deny.lib.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   3.2355  478288  {main}( )   ..\sql.php:0
2   4.3001  644944  require_once( 'C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\common.inc.php' ) ..\sql.php:12
3   30.9048 4159600 include_once( 'C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\ip_allow_deny.lib.php' )  ..\common.inc.php:874
```

but the thing is that these people got the error while they were tying to access the table via script and I on the other hand was trying the same through php my admin console, now my question is that when I am accessing it via localhost then how can I get this error?

even if I set `ini_set('max_execution_time', 240)` but still I don't want to because I want the time limit to be the same. Any help will be appreciated.